# Number in wordpress menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu

[Menu of wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fFF4.png)

My question is simple , i want to make a menu like the one in jobs. I think it is something with jquery but i'm not sure how to implement it in wordpress.

I was searching for info but i could not find any.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with multiple ways:
I suggest 1 as below:

```
    //put below code in your theme's function.php
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpml_lang_nav_menu_item', 10, 2);
    function wpml_lang_nav_menu_item($items, $args) {
    // Your code goes here
if($items['jobs']){
$items['jobs']+="<span>Your counter</span>";
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an $.ajax call to backend file (php or whatever you're using) that returns the number of elements you need to know.

If the call is successfull and returns a quantity, you can add the element with jQuery to the menu item, styling it with CSS as you want. Another option is having the item always there and hide it and show it.

If you want the number to be updated automatically, you can create and interval with `setInterval()` and put the ajax call and the rest inside of it.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you should get number of job(post) from ajax then append it on menu

something like this in your theme js file

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: ({
        action: 'getJobCount',
      }),
      success: function (data) {
        $('.menu li span').append(data);
      }
    });
```

**PHP**

```
function getJobCount(){

    echo wp_count_posts('page'); // post type

}
```